# Explaining for loop inside while loop

Tags: loops, nested-loops

I am currently studying for my upcoming java test. I am doing some revision questions where you have to determine the value of 'number' after the loop(s). 
I have the following loops:

```
//Loop 1
int number = 0;
while(number < 10) {
    for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        number = number + 2;
    }
}
//Loop 2
int number = 0;
do {
    for( in t i =0; i <20; i ++) {
        number ++;
    }
} while (number < 10);
```

So, for Loop 1, I am thinking that:

```
//i = 10, number = 0 + 2 = 2
//i = 9, number = 2 + 2 = 4
//i = 8, number = 4 + 2 = 6
//i = 7, number = 6 + 2 = 8
```

So I thought 8 ought to be the last number, as 10 is not less than 10. But this isn't right. How can I understand these loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take a pencil and a paper and you do:

`for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--)` will be executed 10 times (For each time you enter the *while* loop). So `number` will be 20.
Then you'll go back to check the condition of the *while*, and `number` won't satisfy the condition. So we exit the loop.

Remember that you'll go back to the *while* only after you finish executing the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So the conditions of the outer loop do not affect the inner loop until we break out from it? That is, the while-loop [while(number < 10)] does not detect that number has passed 10 before we are done with the inner for-loop?

Comment: Exactly. As long as you are in the scope of the `for` loop, you don't check the condition in the `while`. When the `for` finishes, you go back to the `while` loop.

Comment: @aprilrocks92 Good luck in your exam :)